# Google Maps map marker hover text

Tags: google-maps

When you search for a company in maps, you can hover your mouse over the map and see additional text.

This looks like it comes from the website of the company, from the metadescription, or body if no metadescription exists.

Example:

[image]

See "Welcome to FMD..." below the marker.

The description of this site in Google's index no longer reflects the short text below, so perhaps it comes from somewhere else?  Note that this it is not in Places directly, it got here through Google's indexing process.

Is there a way to trigger an update to this text?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit it manually and sent it to Google, but the best way is to be the owner of that place. Set up Google+ page that ties to the address, name, etc, and get a Google account for the same.

Once you've followed all of Google's instructions for ensuring you are the author of site(s) and owner, your info will show up in serps and maps.